# How to log string then array on one line using Mule logger component

Tags: mule, mulesoft, anypoint-studio, mule4

I want to log a string using an expression like `'payload = ' + payload`
where payload is an array on one log line
however I can't determine how to add string before the payload without it complaining about concat string and array.

Logging just an array or just a string works with no issue.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert the array to a string, using Java convention, with the write() function. Then just use the `++` operator to concatenate. A single `+` is only for numeric operations, not concatenation. I used single quotes to avoid conflicts with the enclosing double quotes of the expression, however if you are using the UI editor it will take care of escaping the quotes. I'm more used to the XML view.

```js
"#['payload=' ++ write(payload, 'application/json', {indent: false})]"
```

Output:

```
payload=[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Alternatively you can use reduce() to convert the array to a string manually but 90% of the time write() will be simpler and I expect more performant:

```
'payload=' ++ (payload reduce ((item, accumulator="[") -> accumulator ++ (if (sizeOf(accumulator) == 1) "" else ",") ++ item as String)) ++ "]"
```

Comment: you are right @Aled, first option is more recommended

Comment: first option prints java memory address not values, payload=org.mule.runtime.core.internal.streaming.object.ManagedCursorIteratorProvider@f635303 (second option results in runtime error but I am not going to use that anyway)

Comment: Ah, the input is in a stream. What data type is the payload? JSON, XML, Java?

Comment: the input was Array from database rows, without logger outputs http listener to json, I was trying to print array values. The database has 2 rows which I eventually want be Map (which looks like I found out how to do in select) but array and map give same error trying to log with string text

Comment: I have updated my answer to convert the output of write() to JSON without indentation. That should give you a printable result.

Comment: json change works for logging so I will use that, is there way to customize the Array/Map by extending java.util class with custom toString and using that toString response?

Comment: As your first test showed the implementation class is not a Java collection but a managed stream implementation of Mule, so no. And probably extend those classes is not a good idea anyway. If the payload was an array/maps my first version would have worked. You should not assume Java classes while working in Mule4 flows. It's a bad practice.

Comment: when using Database Connector is it always going return some internal mule stream object?

Comment: Probably, but you should not assume a given implementation class. That was my mistake in the first version of my answer.